# 42601:Token * was not valid DB2 for IBM i (AS400)

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, sql-insert

I would like to insert in a DB2 AS 400 database.  I would like to insert a string that includes an asterisk.  I receive the error

```
42601:Token * was not valid (list of valid tokens) SQL code 104
```

Searching in the Internet generally, and stackoverflow specifically has not revealed relevant information.

Comment: Can you share the insert statement please?

Comment: error message = -104
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES (*text);Error 42601:Token * was not valid. Valid tokens:

Answer (score 3):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`). It seems your statement had omitted them, and hence the error. Applying them to your value should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES ('*text')
```